# How to ensure a dereference happens only once

Tags: c++, pointers, c++17, volatile, dereference

Is there a way to ensure that a dereference happens only once and the value from the dereference is loaded-from/stored-to only once? For example

```
class X {
public:
  std::pair<int, int> p;
};

void bar(std::pair<int, int>);

void foo(X* pointer) {
  auto pr = pointer->p;
  bar(pr);
}

int main() {
  auto&& go = std::atomic<bool>{false};
  auto&& x = X{};
  auto&& thread = std::thread{[&]() {
    while (!go.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) {}
    foo(&x);
  }};

  x = create();
  go.store(true, std::memory_order_release);
  thread.join();
}
```

It's valid for the compiler to load from the pointer more than once, is there a way to ensure that the load(s) happens only once? If I add volatile to `foo()` I can't pass the dereferenced pair to `bar()` because I would be casting away `volatile`-ness from `p`.

---

An example of where this could be useful is if you have a device that is connected to receive IO from one of the device's ports. Then it's important that you only read from the pointer once. As each read means something to the device. Further if you have other code that does not deal with volatile types, then it would be important to dereference the pointer, and pass a non-volatile object to the external code.

Comment: You''ll get hints from your friendly compiler. Edit: g++ 9 gives hints. Please make it a [mcve].

Comment: It sounds like it might be worth making your own pointer type where dereferencing is actually a "seize" operation. Or it's possible I'm misunderstanding your needs.

Comment: "_If I add volatile to foo() I can't pass the dereferenced_" You will not get away from synching.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem.  What are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: Is that a thread question? Can you use `std::atomic`?

Comment: @NathanOliver I added an example of what I have in mind in the question. Thanks!

Comment: @curiousguy I cannot because this spans more than a single std::atomic<> unfortunately.

Comment: The whole Q is meaningless w/o a discussion of the expected memory visibility requirements. What kind of memory is it? Cached, uncached?

Comment: @curiousguy I'm not too familiar with uncached memory, so let's say it's cacheable. And is loaded from an external device or something. Also tried to clarify memory visibility in the question.

Comment: You should use a special compiler intrinsic or write a driver with a dumb compiler, probably in C. Sounds like C++ is the wrong tool to use here.

Comment: @TanveerBadar I don’t know if that makes sense. C++ code uses compiler instrinsics all the time...

Comment: @TanveerBadar C++ is intended to go as low level as C